# Runtime dictionary on post in webpage

Tags: php, mysql

I want to put dictionary on my site. for that I have created using database But I want to if particular word exist in dictionary that during publication of any post my curson shows its meaning.

I want this in same way like application. that is if we move my cursor on any button that without clicking that it shows name of that button. Similarly, on this column if we move our cursor to `B` button it shows name of that. I want this with meaning thats if curson move to particular word and without making that word as hyperlink or else Simply its meaning is shown..

Is this hover effect? If yes how can I make it combined with php? Please explan with code.

Answer (score 1):

Client-side effects are JavaScript, and the events to bind are `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

Comment: That means I have to add javascript. Can you please give me link for that or related javascript.

Comment: No. This is a programming Q&A site, not a free consulting service.

Comment: What a idiotic reply is this... If u don't wish to comment than why are you doing so?